# What is an applied patch in a Mercurial queue?

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-queue

The documentation is littered with mentions of "applied patches", i.e. in `hg qfold`, it says "Patches must not yet be applied."

How do I apply a patch, and how do I know when a patch is applied? This concept doesn't seem to appear in the output of `hg qser` or its `--help`.

Answer (score 0):

Once I left the `--help` behind, I was able to find this:

`hg qapplied`

Ref: [MqTutorial](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MqTutorial).